# Repeater - compare items and group

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a repeater and at the moment in my first column which is the `console type` column it displays:

under my column header: PS4, PS4, PS4, XBOX ONE, XBOX ONE, Nintendo wii

so it is sorting it but I want it to group so that it only shows one console once 
 I think there should be a way to compare dataItemRow with previous dataItemRow
but not really sure how. Any Suggestions?

```
void rptItems_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        //code here that goes through all items and compares items

    }
}
```

population:

```
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Stored Procedure", conn);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Admin", "ALL"));
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dataset);
        rptItems.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
        rptItems.DataBind();
```

Comment: Where is your data coming from? If it's from SQL then you could use DISTINCT to just get each unique value. Supply your code that is populating the repeater

Comment: I have included that now its coming from a stored procedure I am unable to do a distinct in the actual stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea behind is to `use two repeater controls` (any template based rendering controls). The outer repeater control’s ItemTemplate will host the header information and inner repeater control. The inner repeater control will host the records corresponding to the header (Group By column)

The main logic in Item databound is

> 1. Get the record being bound and get all the records corresponding to group by column and add those into temporary list
> 2. Build the header information with the values from the record being bound
> 3. Bind the records from tempoarary list (from 1) into the inner repeater
> 4. Ignore the record being bound and other records of the same group

If you want code help let me know.

Comment: Ok that might work but if you look at my code I supplied surely all that's let do is if previousDataItemRow != DataItemRow then write dataitemRow(ConsoleTypes) but Im not sure about the syntax

Comment: if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem), Yes this might also work. But i'm doing it in different manner. A bit of reverse logic.

Comment: This is what i'm doing first "if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;" and later i'm binding the inner repeater.

Comment: As I suggested in the comments unless there's a business reason to do this in code, doing at the datasource level is always going to be more efficient and less code to maintain

Comment: @matt_lethargic, I agree with you, but OP's requirement don't seem to be asking for handling it from datasource level. I'm helping him with his own logic.

Comment: @Krunal Patil, I understand that, but sometimes people don't know there's a better way to do things, this is all I'm trying to suggest. And if you're going to do it in code then using Linq and .Distinct would still be better than two repeaters!

Comment: @matt_lethargic, something like this i tried few days back, giving options to OP, all i got was down votes and comment from moderator saying OP's haven't asked for options.

Comment: It does say "Any suggestions" in the question!!

Comment: @matt_lethargic so let the OP decide what he wants, I cannot assume.